# Valgrind showing "invalid write of size 4 at fread" and memory leaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, fread

The `load` function below tries to load contents of file pointed by pointer `file` and save its location at `content` and length in `length`. The code works fine but Valgrind shows the error of "invalid write at fread" and several memory leaks while using `realloc`.

Following is the code:

```
bool load(FILE* file, BYTE** content, size_t* length) {
    // providing default values to content and length
    *content = NULL;
    *length = 0;

    // initializing buffer to hold file data
    int size = 512;
    BYTE* buffer = NULL;
    buffer = malloc(size);
    if(buffer == NULL)
        return false;

    // bytes_read will store bytes read at a time    
    int bytes_read = 0;

    // reading 512 bytes at a time and incrmenting writing location by 512
    // reading stops if less than 512 bytes read
    while((bytes_read = fread(buffer + size - 512 , 1, 512, file)) == 512)
    {
        //increasing the size of 
        size = size + 512;
        if(realloc(buffer,size) == NULL)
        {
            free(buffer);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // undoing final increment of 512 and increasing the size by bytes_read on last iteration
    size = size - 512 + bytes_read;

    // triming buffer to minimum size
    if(size > 0)
    {
        BYTE* minimal_buffer = malloc(size + 1);
        memcpy(minimal_buffer, buffer, size);
        minimal_buffer[size] = '\0';
        free(buffer);    
        *content = minimal_buffer;
        *length = size;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if(realloc(buffer,size) == NULL)
```

It reallocates the buffer, but you don't save the new pointer. The [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function could allocate a new area of memory and copy the data there. It returns the new pointer.

An important note: Don't reassign back to the pointer you pass to the `realloc` function, use a temporary variable. Then if `realloc` fails you won't lose the original pointer and can clean up gracefully.